# Sample size calulation for glmm models

Tags: r, mixed-model, sample-size, statistical-power, glmm

I am trying to calculate the sample size for my next experiment.
I have done a pilot study with 16 participants and made a mixed model using lme4 as below.

```
m <- lmer(choice ~ I_D_gen + (A + B + C |sub), data = df)
```

Here, 'choice' is binomial(1,0), IE is continuous, and all random effects are condition informations consiting of 0 and 1.

I want to know how many participants I should recruit for the next study using the effect size of my pilot study.
I have tried using the simr package as below,

```
m_extended <-extend(m, along = 'sub', n = 100)
power <- powerCurve(m_extended, along = 'sub', test = fixed('I_D_gen'), breaks = c(20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100), nsim = 100)
```

and from the results I got, I think I did something wrong.

[image]

I would wish to know what I did wrong, and how I could fix it.

I am also trying a power simulation with my original model, but for some reason is getting (though the code is still running)

> boundary (singular) fit : see help ('isSingular')

Why is this happening? Does it mean the model is not proper?

Thanks!